# Create virtual port from another mac

Tags: macos, operating-systems, usb, serial

I have 2 Macintoshes.
In the first Macintosh I have put in the USB port a device (like a iPod, Arduino, other) and I would like to connect from the second Macintosh to the device on the first.

The two Macintosh are on a LAN.

How can I do that?

Comment: this might not be the right forum...

Answer (score 4):

You will not be able to do this with default osx resources, but there is a lot of programs that will allow you to share usb over the network

for example [this one](http://www.net-usb.com/usb-redirector/)

Comment: Thanks for the link! This solution from Eltima (USB Network Gate) really works. Very sorry that it is not free, but it works stable and I am completely satisfied.